# How to map a Stored proc result to an existing DA class

Tags: linq

When I use SQLMetal to create the linq version of one of my stored procs it creates a returned class specific to the proc - I want to map the result to an existing DA table class.

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advise switching from LINQ to SQL to Entity Framework. This is a known issue and has been resolved in EF4 as it allows you to map the return of an SP to a particular data structure.